# Python Dict Grouping by Date on Key

Tags: python-3.x, date, datetime, dictionary, grouping

I have a dict and its keys are dates, its items are some numbers and sum of the numbers with `Total` as shown below. I want to group the keys by year with their sum of `Total` value. I know how to do it if I use fixed dict. But I will always write different changeable dates. My example list is;

```
{
        "15-12-2017" : {
          "1" : "abc",
          "2" : "def",
          "Total" : "2"
        },
        "16-12-2017" : {
          "1" : "ghi",
          "2" : "jkl",
          "3" : "mno",
          "Total" : "3"
        }
        "17-12-2017" : {
          "1" : "ghi",
          "2" : "jkl",
          "3" : "mno",
          "4" : "pqr",
          "Total" : "4"
        }
        "15-12-2018" : {
          "1" : "ghi",
          "2" : "jkl",
          "3" : "mno",
          "Total" : "3"
        }
        "16-12-2018" : {
          "1" : "ghi",
          "2" : "jkl",
          "Total" : "2"
        }
        "18-12-2019" : {
          "1" : "ghi",
          "2" : "jkl",
          "3" : "mno",
          "Total" : "3"
        }
}
```

I want to get a new list like;

```
{"2017":9,"2018":5,"2019":3}
```

I can do only;

```
for key in my_list:
    if key.split('-')[2] == '2017':
        l_2017.append(key)
```

But as I said before, I will insert many changeable dates. How can I cluster them like this format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

date_data = {
    "15-12-2017" : {
        "1" : "abc",
        "2" : "def",
        "Total" : "2"
    },
    "16-12-2017" : {
        "1" : "ghi",
        "2" : "jkl",
        "3" : "mno",
        "Total" : "3"
    },
    "17-12-2017" : {
        "1" : "ghi",
        "2" : "jkl",
        "3" : "mno",
        "4" : "pqr",
        "Total" : "4"
    },
    "15-12-2018" : {
        "1" : "ghi",
        "2" : "jkl",
        "3" : "mno",
        "Total" : "3"
    },
    "16-12-2018" : {
        "1" : "ghi",
        "2" : "jkl",
        "Total" : "2"
    },
    "18-12-2019" : {
        "1" : "ghi",
        "2" : "jkl",
        "3" : "mno",
        "Total" : "3"
    }
}

sums = {}

for date, data in date_data.items():
    year = str(parse(date).year)
    total = int(data['Total'])
    # Update sum if already tracking, otherwise create new entry in dictionary
    sums[year] = sums[year] + total if year in sums else total

print(sums)
```

This gives the output:

```
{'2017': 9, '2018': 5, '2019': 3}
```